# What is MySQL LOAD data INFILE load order?

Tags: mysql, load, file-io

I have a csv file which should be loaded in sequential order so I can update blank person_name field with the previous row's person_name.

I have added a id (auto increment) which I can use to update the blank rows.

**Table person**

```
id   person_name     car      model
1    Fred            Volvo    2001
2                    FIAT     2000
3    Paul            Volvo    2010
```

My doubt is, Can I be confident that the file will always be loaded in sequential order?

Comment: In a relational database, rows in table ***have no order***. So the loading order does not matter.

Comment: I understood that it was not safe to assume so I added row number for the file before loading it. Thanks

Comment: In theory it's true, but there are cases when insertion order is important (for example when considering performance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although documentation does not state that I think it's pretty safe bet that data will inserted into table sequentially, line by line.

**However keep in mind that it does not guarantee that rows will be in any order when retrieved from table**.

Different storage engines may (and do) internally allocate rows differently and retrieve them in completely different order. Therefore it is **not** safe for You to relay on that. You should either number Your rows in input file and use line_id/row_id for further processing or process the file before You load it into MySQL server.

Comment: Thanks, As per your suggestion I have appended the file with numbers using awk '{printf "%s,%s\n",NR,$0}' input.CSV > output.CSV.