# How to import TXT name lists into MYSQL column from beginning

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I have a table **categories** having 12 rows all are having data.

I created a new column **name_eslang** and trying to import name.txt file which is havng:

```
apple
banana
orange
kiwi
```

each names is in next line.

Using:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'name.txt' INTO TABLE categories
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (name_eslang);
```

**Problem:** all values from name.txt file are inserted but after ID 7, and I want it to be inserted from ID 1 to 6 instead.

[image: It adds after 7 to 10]

My table catgeories:

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_eslang` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

INSERT INTO `categories` (`id`, `name`, `name_eslang`) VALUES
(1, 'Accessories', ''),
(2, 'Cover', ''),
(3, 'Logos', ''),
(4, 'Story', ''),
(5, 'Editing', ''),
(6, 'Gaming', '');


ALTER TABLE `categories`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  ADD KEY `name` (`name`);


ALTER TABLE `categories`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=7;
```

Comment: If you are speaking about the id column being something after 1000, it happens because probably your id column has auto increment. If you would like the id to start from 1 you can reset the auto increment using `ALTER TABLE categories AUTO_INCREMENT = 1` and then insert the data.    **!!!Be very cautious because you could mess up your database if you try to reset the auto increment. If you are working on a test environment and trying to learn or experiment you can do it, but avoid doing it in production environment**

Comment: To clarify, your table categories had multiple columns already before you added column name_eslang? Now you want each nth row to have the name_eslang column updated with the corresponding nth value in the text file?

Comment: @SimonGoater Yes right. Want the same.

Comment: @codtex Tried that too. nothing changed.  1000 rows inserted.
Inserted row id: 2000 (Query took 0.0099 seconds.)
LOAD DATA INFILE 'categories.txt' INTO TABLE categories FIELDS TERMINATED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (name_hilang);

Comment: I don't think you can use LOAD DATA for this. If it's a one-off, you can use a spreadsheet to generate 1000 UPDATE statements.

Comment: use `SHOW CREATE TABLE categories` and post the result into your question, so it might be easier for people to help you. Also it would be helpful to see part of the content in the file `name.txt`

Comment: I don't think you can trust LOAD DATA to preserve the input order of your fruit which is clearly of importance here. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897105/what-is-mysql-load-data-infile-load-order. I think you need a script to either create an UPDATE statement for each row or export your table to a file, modify the file, then reLOAD it. Like I said before, you could just do it in a spreadsheet if you don't want to write code.

Comment: Well, what you want to do is not possible with simple `LOAD DATA INFILE` call, you will need to build more complex logic